# Problemas al agregar Google Services en build.gradle , Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, build.gradle

me explico .

Estoy trabajando en Flutter para integrar el botón de Login de Google, entonces me esta pidiendo que agregue en mi App de Flutter , en el apartado de android/build.gradle este codigo :

```
plugins {
  // ...

  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
  id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false

}
```

Entonces mi código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    plugins {
        id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Pero me da error seguido , este concretamente , probe a meter un build script a parte pero no tengo manera de que funcione.

[image: Captura de pantalla del error build.gradle]

Muchas gracias por llegar hasta aquí , agradezco todo tipo de ayuda ! :D